# How to go from basic UINavigationController to UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I've been working on a personal project for a while now, and I'd like to make it enjoyable on iPad, or at least better than currently.

My app consist of three tabs embedded in a UITabbarController with one of them being a UITableViewController. That tableView presents a list of medication, with the possibility to search them with a search bar at the top. When clicking one of the medication we're taken to another viewController using a segue that shows all informations about it.

(I am using storyBoard for this project)

My question is, how can I move from what I have already done to using a UISplitViewController? I mean do I have to re start all my controllers? I don't understand how to start, or where to start?

Should I start with a brand new UISplitViewController and copy/past the code I've already written and then adapt it? Or should I make changes to my actual viewControllers in order to "convert" them to UISplitViewController?

I've been using Swift for around 6 months, I have never used a UISplitViewController as of today.

Thanks in advance for your time and advices, Baptiste FAURE.

PS. Do I need to add any images or part of my code?

Comment: Hey, Faure. It would be easier for us to start with what you already have. First, you could show the storyboard you have, because we don't know current state.
Then, it is always better to reuse and update a current solution rather create new from scratch (opinion-based).
Otherwise, you could try both approaches you mentioned and see - the best practice that you ever get: learning by doing.
Here is also a [link regarding UISplitViewControllers](https://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer ! I'm going to take screenshot of my storyboard right now and add them to my question. I think you're right I should just try both solutions and see what works best, I will read the link you gave me and see if that help me ;)